# RUBY script: Wait for ANY output when connected to Telnet session

Tags: ruby, telnet

I am using ruby script to send commands to the UT. I have successfully established telnet session to the remote UT. The commands sent perform series of operation and gives me the statistics.

Initially, after successfully sending the command, I designed UT to send an OK to script which is received. How do I receive the statistics information? The script doesn't know the output of command in advance and each command will have its own string.

Using ruby, how can I tell telnet::waitfor() command to wait for so long duration but break out if UT sends something.?

To read the OK, i used:

```
response=@newSession.waitfor({"String" => "OK\n", "Timeout" => time_out})
```

where, newSession holds the telnet session connection.

```
@newSession = Net::Telnet::new("Session"        => @session,
                                    "Host"      => @ut_ip,
                                    "Port"      => @port_num,
                                    "Timeout"   => 10,
                                    "Prompt"    => /[$%#>] \z/n)
```

I cant use "Match" or "Prompt" since I don't know what I am gonna get.! Help me out guys.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s read the documentation on [`Net::Telnet`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/net/telnet/rdoc/Net/Telnet.html):

> For some protocols, it will be possible to specify the Prompt option once when you create the Telnet object and use `cmd()` calls; for others, you will have to specify the response sequence to look for as the Match option to every `cmd()` call, or call `puts()` and `waitfor()` directly; **for yet others, you will have to use `sysread()` instead of `waitfor()` and parse server responses yourself**.

So, you are about to handle the `IO` yourself and [`#preprocess`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/net/telnet/rdoc/Net/Telnet.html#method-i-preprocess) it.